# Openshift use for Commercial web sites

Tags: paas, openshift

Can we use OpenShift Express, which is free right now, for commercial web applications?

And if not, then which PAAS services are there which are free, and have no vendor lock-in.

Answer (score 10):

You can use OpenShift Express for commercial web apps but be sure it will meet your requirements. Potential issues include:

- currently no outgoing email support
- currently applications do not scale to accommodate load
- 1GB disc space limit
- shared hosting
- limit 3 cartridges (DB, metrics, etc) per app
- no official support from Red Hat. Documentation is good and [community forum](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/forums/openshift) support is very active.

OpenShift would meet many commercial site requirements. I think it's a great option. For more info read the [FAQ](https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/faq).

Answer (score 7):

Openshift have opened SMTP Port now.
check : https://www.redhat.com/openshift/community/blogs/outbound-mail-ports-are-now-open-for-business-on-openshift

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Cloudify](http://cloudifysource.org). It is build for orchestrating any application on any Cloud without changing the application code or architecture. Cloudify is opensource and free.

Cloudify offers many features such as pluggable monitoring, scale rules by any KPI, APIs for sharing runtime information between agents and even Chef integration

Due Diligence Im the product manager for Cloudify in GigaSpaces

Comment: You should mention you work for cloudify. It's just better when all interests are declared.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using it for some small services and clients.
There isn't any clause on there [terms of use](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/legal/site_terms) that states that you can't use it as commercial web apps. But attention to the following line:

"You may not post or transmit through this website advertising or commercial solicitations; promotional materials relating to website or online services which are competitive with Red Hat and/or this website."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, OpenShift has a tier that is completely free to use, even for commercial applications. There are no plans to change this in the future. There are, however, some [minor limitations](//openshift.com/developers/pricing) to the FreeShift tier:

- Scaling limited to 3 gears

  - Serves about 15 pages/second
  - 3GB total storage space (1GB per gear)
- No SSL certificate for your custom domain name
- No support from Red Hat

---

An alternative is [Heroku](//heroku.com), which you should definitely check out if you haven't already. Having used both, I can tell you that it's a much more polished platform: The servers are about 4× faster, you can run as many apps as you want, and the Heroku Toolbelt is much more powerful than the OpenShift's Client Tools. Heroku is also completely free until you reach 10k rows in your database.

Comment: It is possible to set up an SSL certificate for a custom domain, even on the free plan. They don't seem to have updated their pricing page to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

RedHat will provide support (and scaling) when they release their MegaShift tier.
(https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/pricing)
I don't think there is a date yet for this.

It won't be for free off course.